# Ruby / Twitter Gem. Twitter::Error::NotFound

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems, twitter-gem

Happy holidays!

With the Twitter gem, I occasionally get this [error](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/Error/NotFound) when doing a [lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup) on a batch of ids. Is there a way to know which of the ids weren't found, and which were?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when either all of the ids you pass are not found or you only pass one id and it is not found. If at least one of the ids you pass is available then you will get back a list with that value and not any of the missing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get this message as twitter cannot give back ids of private users, so this might help:
before asking for ids put this...

a_user = Twitter.user(screen_name)
if a_user.protected != true
  {
   ...
  }